# Make jQuery(document).ready(function() fire again when a div opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**How do I get jQuery(document).ready(function() to fire again when an overlay div is activated?**

I'm using this function to hide the a.button:

```
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(
'.theme-actions a.button.button-primary.customize.load-customize.hide-if-no-customize'
).css("display","none");
});
});
```

The same button with the same class exists in a "overlay" called .theme-wrap, and within .theme-wrap, the a.button CSS looks like this (the difference being `.active-theme` ):

```
.theme-actions .active-theme a.button.button-primary.customize.load-customize.hide-if-no-customize
```

If I reload the page with the .theme-wrap overlay open, the button disappears, because the jQuery document ready function fires again.

I tried adding both CSS rules to the one function

```
jQuery(
'.theme-actions a.button.button-primary.customize.load-customize.hide-if-no-customize,
.theme-actions .active-theme a.button.button-primary.customize.load-customize.hide-if-no-customize
    ').css("display","none");
```

but it doesn't work.

How do I get document ready to fire again when the overlay opens?

**Update 10/14/14**

*As was pointed out in the answer below: there is no need for jQuery in this instance. The CSS I'm using is the same for each div - the original and the overlay - so a simple `{display:none}` rule added to the admin stylesheet will suffice.*

Comment: which is the overlay plugin used? and how is it loaded

Comment: Note: `jQuery(function($) {` is the same as document ready, so there is no need to use `jQuery(document).ready(function () {..}) inside it

Comment: I'm assuming the `.active-theme` overlay doesn't exist in the DOM on document load, thats why it doesn't work. I'm not sure you'd want to fire a `$(document).ready()` function again, Also you have some redundancies in your code.  Can we see the code for the overlay? Also, any reason you'r not just adding the CSS directly to your stylesheet?

Comment: a solution might look something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hjrhwfLe/2/

Comment: @Matthew Brown: why I didn't think of that? That works; I just tested it. Much simpler and cleaner; no need for jQuery. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: thanks, that makes sense, but MatthewBrown pointed out that all I need is CSS, and that's far simpler. I was trying to make things too complex.

Comment: @songdogtech Answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `$(document).ready()` function again, try adding the CSS directly to your stylesheet.

Comment: You're right; thanks. No need for jQuery. I had to hook into admin to add a new stylesheet with the one {display:none} rule, but that was easy.

Answer (score 0):

Once the overlay is activated run the following:

```
jQuery('.theme-actions .active-theme a.button.button-primary.customize.load-customize.hide-if-no-customize
').css("display","none");
```

Or better still create a function:

```
function hideElement( sel) {
    $( sel ).hide(); //.hide() is equiv to .css('display', 'none');
}
```

Then call the function at `DOM ready` with first selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hideElement( 'selector-1' );
});
```

And then when the overlay is fully activated, call the function with the appropriate selector:

```
hideElement( 'selector-2' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but as pointed out above, there is no need for jQuery; I was making things too complex.